# Ignore validator on edit view

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a subcategory form like this:

```
class SubcategoryForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), 
        max_length=100,
        label='Subcategory',
        validators=[unic_subcategory]
    )
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
        queryset = Category.objects.filter(delete=False),
        label='Category'
    )
```

The validator function looks like this:

```
def unic_subcategory(value):
    exist = Subcategory.objects.filter(nome=value)
    if exist:
        raise ValidationError(u"Duplicated subcategory '%s' are not allowed" % value)
```

This works when the user creates a new subcategory and a subcategory with the same name already exists. My problem comes when the user tries to edit the `category` field and not the `name` field. The form raises an error because the `name` field already exists.

How can I avoid this when the user edits the `category` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validator is not the right tool for this jobs. Validators are intended for eliminating content that is *universally* unfit for a given field. If you need to check more complex conditions add a clean method:

```
def clean_name(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
    if self.instance and self.instance.name == value:
        return  # name didn't change, skip the check
    if Subcategory.objects.filter(name=value).exists():
        raise ValidationError(u"Duplicated subcategory '%s' is not allowed" % value)
```

Comment: This work with the edit, but when I tried with a new subcategory that already exist gives me the debug error from django/sql but not the form error.

Comment: @M.Gar I corrected my code. You've got what I presume is a typo in the queryset filter in your code (`nome` instead of `name`), so I changed it to `name` also.

Comment: Thanks, but now gives me this error `'SubcategoryForm' object has no attribute 'instance'`

Comment: Ok just change `def clean_name` for `clean_data` and takes `instance`, thank you

Answer (score -2):

You can just add a validation for `category`.

```
def unic_subcategory(name, categ):
    subc_name = Subcategory.objects.filter(name=name)
    subc_categ = Subcategory.objects.filter(categ=categ)
    if all([exist, categ]):
        raise ValidationError(u"Duplicated subcategory '%s' and category %s are not allowed" % [name, categ])
```